# Change Hierarchy of xml node based on occurrence

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to move a node at same level under it's preceding node based on the number of time it comes. Trying this with XSLT code.

Pay,Remit,Trailer can repeat in xml. But each pay will be followed by n number of remit nodes. 
where in the output . pay should contain all the remit node just below it.

I have tried using XSLT code but somehow I not getting the expected result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  method="xml" encoding='UTF-8'/>
<!--Identity template, 
        provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:for-each select="pay">
    <xsl:template match="Remit">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message>
<Record>
    <Header>
        <H></H>
    </Header>
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
    <Pay>
        <BB>1</BB>
        <amount>11</amount>
    </Pay>
    <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
    </Remit>
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
    <Pay>
        <BB>1</BB>
        <amount>78</amount>
    </Pay>
    <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
    </Remit>
    <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
    </Remit>
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
</Record>
</Message>
```

expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Message>
<Record>
    <Header>
        <H>1</H>
    </Header>`enter code here`
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
    <Pay>
        <BB>1</BB>
        <amount>11</amount>
        <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
            </Remit>
    </Pay>
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
    <Pay>
        <BB>1</BB>
        <amount>78</amount>
            <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
            </Remit>
            <Remit>
        <Type>30</Type>
        <Transaction>I</Transaction>
            </Remit>
    </Pay>
    <Trailer>
        <AA>1</AA>
    </Trailer>
</Record>
</Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use case for `for-each-group group-starting-with` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Pay">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::Pay">
                      <xsl:copy>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group()[self::Remit]"/>
                      </xsl:copy>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="(current-group() except .)[not(self::Remit)]"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38Zm

For an XSLT 2 processor replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with your identity template

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group' at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737) at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:343)   @Martin , I guess my tool is using some old java processor. is there still a way that I can achieve this using xslt transformation

Comment: Why did you use the tag for [tag:xslt-2.0] then? Anyway, on the Java platform it is normally easy to put Saxon 9 HE (https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/ or https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE) on the class path and have it execute XSLT 2 or 3.